# Подвисает и лагает Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Добрый день!
Студия ужасно торомозит, сразу скажу, что компьютер очччень силен: i7, 16Гб. Подвисает, когда я печатаю - напишешь пару букв, и все повисло, спустя 2-3 секунды отвисает и буквы пропечатываются. Работать стало невозможно) Студия 3.0, портативная. Приложения отлаживаю на планшете, т.е. не на ВМ. Подскажите, кто сталикивался с подобными проблемами и как их решить?

P/S/ первые 2 месяца работала хорошо, такого не было( У коллеги такая же проблема.

Comment: может быть поставили какой то плагин или неудачную версию (например, бета билд). Одно время в idea была бага с отрисовкой содержимого поиска - оно отрисовывалось на каждое движение мышки.

Comment: может кэш или чтото подобное скачайте сиклейнер и очищайте от лишнего мусора свои компьютер

Comment: запустил invalidate caсhe - вроде поправилось, хотя не всегда помогает.